# Working Durable Functions Project no longer works locally after upgrading to VS2022 17.1.4

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a .NET 6, V4 Durable Functions project which no longer runs locally since I upgraded to Visual Studio 17.1.3 (and 17.1.4). I get the following error (the critical bit being the storage connection string which is specified in `local.settings.json`):

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4426 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.1.3.17473

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
[2022-04-13T13:39:54.245Z] Using the default storage provider: AzureStorage.
[2022-04-13T13:39:54.245Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '9291bc18-db2c-4cf3-ad6a-1b1b03882388'.
[2022-04-13T13:39:54.248Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

I have tried running earlier releases of the Azure Functions Core Tools and also tried local debugging with Visual Studio Code but always get the same error. I therefore conclude that something very low-level is broken.

##### Project File

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\tests\RemitlyCallbacks.Mocks\RemitlyCallbacks.Mocks.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Entities\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

##### local.settings.json

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

##### host.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "<myHubName>",
            "storageProvider": {
                "connectionStringName": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The latest release of Azure Functions Core Tools mentions changes to variable names but I can't find specific details about what may have changed.

I am now out of ideas as to how to get my local debugging experience back. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @PriyankSheth If I recall correctly, it ended up being a typo in my local.settings.json.